# Javascript toLocaleString does not use the correct format

Tags: javascript

It seems to me that javascript's number `toLocaleString()` and .NET `ToString()` format numbers differently. `toLocaleString()` seems to ignore the language I set in Tools/Internet Options/Languages.

For example, to test spanish support I made sure only Spanish (es-ES) is listed in Tools/Internet Options/Languages but

`alert((12.05).toLocaleString());` still shows "12.05" (instead of 12,05)

The Accepted-Language in the header shows es-ES but `navigator.userLanguage` in javascript still says "en-US" (as if it were picked from the OS)

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not missing anything. `toLocaleString` gets the current locale from the [operating system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString).

**edit in response to comment**

That browser setting tells the server what language(s) you prefer. It has no effect on javascript, however. And if you think about it that makes perfect sense. Asking the server for content in a particular language is no guarantee that the server will actually return content in that language.

But it sounds to me like you don't really have a problem, you were just confused about how to test properly. Can't you just change the OS language settings to ensure that the date is properly formatted for Spanish speakers?

Comment: If so, what's the point of the having language settings in the browsers?

Answer (score 0):

The only language the matters is the one of the browser or operating system - and that one is returned in `navigator.userLanguage`.

The `accept-languages` header/setting is merely for websites to determine which language the user prefers; not to affect code behaviour.